# Why session data is not persisting when accessed on different js pages in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I am setting session data in MongoDB storage on login and clearing it on logout but the problem is when I try to access those session data from a different js file than where it was stored,It prints undefined.

My app.js file:

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieparser())
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/assets'));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: config.mongoUri }),
  
  })
)
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUri,{ useNewUrlParser: true },()=>{
    console.log('connected to db')
})
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
  throw new Error(`unable to connect to database`)
})
app.use('/', userRoutes)
app.use('/', authRoutes)
app.use('/', postRoutes)


app.listen(config.port)
```

My auth.js file where the session data is stored:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj);
});
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "789965715216-2sbi4nk44kbaabtsqt7vlddgklieksq9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "Jtdl2O8dBSJnTUrJ9I6UEBhf",
    callbackURL: "https://openforumsocial.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      userProfile=profile;
      return done(null, userProfile);
  }
));
router.get('/auth/google', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));
 
router.route('/auth/google/callback').get(passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/error' }),function(req,res){
  
    req.session.user=userProfile
    console.log(req.session.user)
    res.json(userProfile)
  
    
}

)

router.get('/logout', (req, res) =>{ 
   req.session.destroy()
   res.send("logged out")

});
```

My controller.js file where its printing undefined on being queried:

```
const requireSignin = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session.user)
  if (
    expressJwt({
      secret: config.jwtSecret,
      userProperty: "auth",
      algorithms: ["sha1", "RS256", "HS256"],
    }) ||
    req.session.user
  )
    next();
};
```

When I try to console `req.session.user`,it prints undefined.Can someone help me with what i am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: From what i can understand, you're storing the session inside `req` object.

In express, each request is separated, meaning you will have a lot of `req` object.

Imagine this, when u login and what not, you get the session and store it in the `req` lets call it `req login`. Then you proceed to respond to client with whatever u want to do,.

Then the client route to the next page, and you get another `req`, however this `req` is not `req login`, it is totally different object. That is why it is giving you undefined. So what you should do it either store the info clientside, or have a list

Comment: or have an object/array that store the list of currently login person (You can use something like memory cache to do it) and retrieve it from there.